# How to instantly fill in a text box on change using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a textbox which fills in the city. I have an autocomplete feature for that and its the standard autocomplete feature with data coming in from the db.

The data coming in has city, state and country information.When the user selects the city from the autocomplete dropdown, it should populate the city, state and country. So I have an onchange on the city for this. The problem is that the state and country are filled only when I click on the respective textboxes and not instantly as it happens with on change.
Code:

```
$(".find-city").autocomplete(cityConfirmAutoCompleteOption);
$(".find-city").autocomplete( "option", "appendTo", "#"+'button'+q.id );

$(".find-city").change(function(city) {
$(".state").val(statecode);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="find-city"  style="float: left;">
<table>             
<tbody><tr><td><label>City</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="find-city"></td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div> 

<div class="state"  style="float: left;">
<table>             
<tbody><tr><td><label>State</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="state"></td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Could you provide some of the HTML and more of the JavaScript?

Comment: `change` event does not get triggered until you actually click and change the value of the dropdown.

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz Yeah so even after I click on the option for city, It only gets triggered(the state gets filled) when I click on the state textbox. Shouldnt it be after I click on the dropdown and make the selection?

Comment: Trying to understand your code, where do you get the `statecode` ?

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz  cityConfirmAutoCompleteOption is the function in which I query the database. The datebase returns the list of city names and the corresponding state codes.

Comment: yeah but where do you set `var satecode = "myStateCode"`?

Comment: within the function.

Comment: I think we still need to see more HTML and JavaScript. We need to see how you set statecode, what the value of cityConfirmAutoCompletionOption is, and we should see what your select input looks like (.find-city).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your HTML and most of your JavaScript, 
Could you not just do this:

```
$(".find-city").change(function(city) {
    $(".state").val(statecode);
    $(".city").val(citycode);
    //... etc.
});
```

Comment: I added the HTML. I tried this. The state textbox does get populated but ONLY after I click on the state textbox.

Comment: See my comment on your question requesting some more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problem trying to set the value of the input box, try this:

```
$('.state').attr('value',stateCode);
```

You can see similar demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwhw4sj9/